# Separating Knockout.js, Node.js, and Standalone API but maintain two bindings and other functionalities

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, mvvm, knockout.js

I've given myself an exercise to understand how one could write a scalable API independently of an MV* framework to be used in non-DOM environment. The desirable end result would be to have a class library or sorts, that is then in turn utilized by MV* framework such as Knockout, which I use in the example below.

The biggest challenge I've found so far is to dealing with retaining two-way bindings. In order to do this, the underlying properties are required to be observable.

```
// no DOM in here, just the basics
function QueryRequest(){

};

QueryRequest.prototype = {
    get preference() {
        return this._preference;    
    },
    set preference(val) {
        this._preference = val;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what a function definition would look like from the library.

```
function QueryRequestViewModel() {
    QueryRequest.call(this);

    // DOM interaction safe in here...
    this.preference = ko.observable('Pizza');
};

// inherit from QueryRequest, then point the constructor back to the view model, base we already call base.
QueryRequestViewModel.prototype = new QueryRequest();
QueryRequestViewModel.prototype.constructor = QueryRequestViewModel; 
ko.applyBindings(new QueryRequestViewModel()); // bind
```

Here is the view model, which is not independent but would inherit from QueryRequest.

```
<input id="user-desire" type="text" name="desire" maxlength="500" data-bind="value: preference" />
```

Everything almost works but there's a tad annoying issue.

When knockout goes to set the variable, it is not setting just the primitive, it wants to set it's own object back. Obviously, this is not the desired outcome.

My only requirement is that knockout and any DOM-related code can not be in the library.

Is there another way of achieving what I want? I'm open to the of another MV* library which takes a different approach at observing attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to acheive? I've adapted your code into a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/6Lkv3/3/

Just some basic view model inheritance. Since I am setting `preference` as an observable in the base view model, it is accessible in view models that inherit that base.

```
// no DOM in here, just the basics
var QueryRequest = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.preference = ko.observable();
}

    function QueryRequestViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        // inherit from QueryRequest, then point the constructor back to the view model, base we already call base. 
        QueryRequest.call(self);

        self.setPreference = function () {
            self.preference("Pizza");
        }
    };


ko.applyBindings(new QueryRequestViewModel());
```

And you could pass options to a base view model like this, http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/6Lkv3/4/

Comment: I understand what you have done but, I do want the use of Knockout code within the function definition of QueryRequest. This same code is to be in a non dom environment. Therefore, only the view model should contain any references to knockout but still retain the full functionality of events, bindings, etc.